# Import to Data Extension even if the CSV file has no rows (and has only header)

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, import

An import step of my automation fails. I tried to imitate that import manually and I realized that Salesforce does not continue the import when the file is empty. In my case, my file contains only the header and no rows.

But I do want to overwrite the destination Data Extension even when there are no rows. If the file is empty, I simply would like my Data Extension to be empty, too.

How can I let empty files count as import as well?

Answer (score 8):

In order to do this, you will need to contact SFMC Support and request a business rule "**Allow Blank File Processing**" to be enabled on your instance.

This allows the import of empty files without halting the process.
By default the settings in the backend force a *stop* on blank imports, but with this business rule enabled it is changed to continue.

Comment: I will do this! Thank you! So far, half of my development time for the SF account I am working on has gone to asking for permissions and checkboxes about which I had no idea.

Comment: I have created a support ticket now. I will come back and choose this an answer as soon as the SF support person confirms this.